# Unable to bind properties using custom controls in UWP in a ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `ListView` in UWP which displays a list of custom controls `CustomControl`. Reading around I have seen that other users have face similar issues and their solution mostly revolved around setting the `DataContext` of their controls, but I cannot understand how I can do that in my example.  In order to dynamically update the view I used `DependencyProperties` in my model which is the following:

```
    public class DataObject : DependencyObject
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(nameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(nameProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for name.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty nameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(DataObject), new PropertyMetadata("Name"));
    }
```

Then in my main page I implemented the following logic to change the `Name` of my third element:

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<DataObject> dataList;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.dataList = new ObservableCollection<DataObject>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
                dataObject.Name = "Item " + i.ToString();

                this.dataList.Add(dataObject);
            }
            DataListView.ItemsSource = dataList;

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var obj = dataList.ElementAt(2);

            obj.Name = "Hello!";

        }
    }
```

The XAML for the main page is the following:

```
<Page
    x:Class="ListViewTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:ListViewTest.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="DataListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:CustomControl DisplayName="{Binding Name}"></controls:CustomControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="92" Width="238"
                Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The custom control `CustomControl` is this:

```
namespace ListViewTest.Controls
{
    public sealed partial class CustomControl : UserControl
    {


        public string DisplayName
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayNameProperty); }
            set { 
                SetValue(DisplayNameProperty, value);
                DisplayText.Text = value;
            }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisplayName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayName", typeof(string), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata("DisplayText"));


        public CustomControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Its structure is very simple:

```
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="ClickButton" Content="Button" Margin="171,165,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock Name="DisplayText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

The problem is that when I click the button nothing happens and I am struggling to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataObject` shouldn't inherit from `DependencyObject`. It should be defined as a CLR object that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class DataObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Also, the setter of the CLR wrapper for the dependency property in `CustomControls` should *only* set the value of the dependency property. You could set the value of the `TextBlock` using a `PropertyChangedCallback`:

```
public sealed partial class CustomControl : UserControl
{
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(DisplayName), typeof(string), typeof(CustomControl), 
            new PropertyMetadata("DisplayText", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnChanged)));

    private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomControl customControl = (CustomControl)d;
        d.DisplayText = e.NewValue as string;
    }

    public CustomControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't a DependencyObject with DependentProperties the "alternative" to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Comment: @daljit97: Not exactly. Data objects shouldn't be have a dependency on `DependencyObject`. You would typically implement them in a .NET Standard class library that you then reference from your client app. And `DataTemplates` may not be applied to `DependencyObjects`.

Comment: Ah I see, this makes sense.

Comment: Ok so I have checked, however you are incorrect about `DependencyObject` inheritance, it turns indeed that it is possible to implement a model using that instead of implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. The problem in my code was that I was trying to set a custom setter for a DependencyProperty which doesn't seem to be possible. So as you suggested, using a `PropertyChangedCallBack` works (although I think it's not really elegant as solution).